# Problem using pandas.get_dummies for a binary feature that returns 3 columns one with a tabulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, encode

I'm working on a binary classification machine learning problem and I use pandas function get_dummies to encode my categorical data. The function works well with all my data but 2 columns where it returns 3 categories for each instead of 2. For instance: I have a feature called "classification" where the value is "ckd" and "notckd". The get_dummies function returns a dataframe with **column1**: *ckd*, **column2**: *ckd\t*, **column3**: *notckd*. I've checked whether there were any tabulations in my data with many methods and there was none. Also, the second column **ckd\t** is 0 everywhere.
I can just drop these supplementary columns but I still want to figure out what causes this problem.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the output of `df["classification"].value_counts()` ?

Comment: Yeah it shows that there are 2 elements ckd\t. I'll see how I can omit tabulations. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df["classification"].str.replace('\t', '',  inplace=True)`